# Освобождение массива double-ов в std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++

Нужен массив double-ов. Количество элементов определяется только во время выполнения программы - поэтому в стеке создать не получится. Необходимо его выделять динамически.

Проблема в том, что если создавать в куче, то придется на выходе из функции его освобождать. Выходов из функций несколько - через время могут появиться еще. Уже звучит не очень.

Появилась идея сделать вот так:

```
int numbElem = /*run time calc */;
std::unique_ptr<double> massive(new double[numbElem]);
```

Как будто все норм, но решил спросить - так делать нормально? Будут ли утечки памяти в таком случае?

Comment: Есть какие-то причины не использовать структуры данных из `stl`?

Comment: А что `std::vector<double>` уже не достаточно модно? И, кстати, в вашем коде `numbElem` задаёт инициализирующее значение, а не кол-во элементов. Тут вообще нет массива, просто один `double`.

Comment: Согласен - опечатка, уже поправил)
По поводу stl - в силу определенных обстоятельств нужен именно массив, а не контейнер

Comment: Тогда надо ещё и в тип `unique_ptr` квадратные скобки пропихнуть. Иначе будет UB при освобождении массива как не массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо за помощь)
В комментариях посоветовали использовать stl - решил мою проблему метод std::vector::data

UPD: Просили расписать подробнее: 
Необходимо было использовать библиотечную функцию, которая принимала размер массива и указатель на начало массива -- например void function(int, const double*).

Почему-то у меня в тот момент в голове надежно закрепилась мысль - "Нужен именно массив". В стеке создать этот массив не получится из за того, что его размер не известен на стадии компиляции, а мне не хотелось думать о том, чтобы вручную освобождать на всех выходах динамический массив. В результате появилось сомнительное решение (смотри таск), которое вызывало вопросы - с чем я и пришел сюда. В комментариях справедливо заметили - "почему не std::vector". Этот вопрос решил все проблемы - теперь в качестве первого параметра передается vector::size, а в качестве второго - vector::data, который возвращает указатель на массив, выделенный в куче. Контейнер сам занимается выделением и освобождением этой памяти - мне не пришлось с этим возиться на всех выходах функции.

Comment: А можете чуть подробнее расписать?

Comment: *"в качестве первого параметра передается vector::size, а в качестве второго - vector::data, который возвращает указатель на массив"* - у вас функция, сигнатуру которой вы не можете менять? Типа вызова API? Просто зачем передавать так, если проще передать [если нужно - константную] ссылку на `vector`?

Comment: Да, менять сигнатуру функции нельзя.

Answer (score 5):

Что-то мне кажется, что вы хотите

```
int numbElem = /*run time calc */;
std::unique_ptr<double[]> massive(new double[numbElem]);
```

А так - все нормально.

*"По-моему, так". (с) Пух*

P.S. Но, в принципе, то же самое можно достичь и другими, более простыми способами. Но об этом уже сказали в комментариях..

Comment: Другой вариант записи: `auto massive = std::make_unique<double[]>(numbElem);`.